# Need help finding a solution (if it exists) for a modular arithmetic formula for three numbers a, b, and c

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have three numbers, a, b, and c. They can be any real or integer value. Here are the three expressions that we look at:

$S_1 = a + b + (a\bmod c) +  (b\bmod c)$

$S_2 = a + a + (a\bmod c) +  (a\bmod c)$

$S_3 = b + b + (b\bmod c) +  (b\bmod c)$

I need some values a, b, and c where either:

$S_2 > S_1$ and $S_3 > S_1$

or:

$S_2 < S_1$ and $S_3 < S_1$

In other words, we need a case where both $S_2$ *and* $S_3$ are above $S_1$ on the number line, or a case where both $S_2$ *and* $S_3$ are below $S_1$ on the number line. I have tried every combination of (a, b, c) where all three are integers and a is in the interval (1,1000), b is in the interval (-1,-1000), and c is in the range (1,1000), but have had no luck with getting a solution. Is it possible to either show that there is a real-valued solution of a, b, and c to this problem, or is it possible to prove that no solution exists?

Here is a possible proof that no solution exists.

Assume, to the contrary, and without loss of generality, that $$ a + a + (a\bmod c) +  (a\bmod c) > a + b + (a\bmod c) +  (b\bmod c)$$

Thus,

$$ a + (a\bmod c) > b + (b\bmod c)$$

Also, let

$$ b + b + (b\bmod c) +  (b\bmod c) > a + b + (a\bmod c) +  (b\bmod c)$$

Then

$$ b + (b\bmod c) > a + (a\bmod c) $$

But $ a + (a\bmod c) > b + (b\bmod c)$, producing a contradiction.

QED?

Comment: Hint:  $2S_1=S_2+S_3$.

Comment: @lulu I just saw your comment after writing a proof by contradiction that no solution exists. Is what I wrote sound? No possible values that can satisfy my system of inequalities, right?

Comment: I didn't look at what you wrote.  Since $2S_1=S_2+S_3$ we clearly can't have $S_1$ greater (or smaller) than both $S_2,S_3$.

Comment: I see no issue with your method. But Lulu's method is definitely shorter to write. :)

Comment: Requirement is equivalent to $(S_2-S_1)(S_3-S_1)>0$. Then $(a+(a\bmod c)-b-(b\bmod c))(b+(b\bmod c)-a-(a\bmod c))>0$, $-(a+(a\bmod c)-b-(b\bmod c))^2>0$, $(a+(a\bmod c)-b-(b\bmod c))^2<0$, which is impossible for real numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_1 = (a + b) + (a \mod c) + (b \mod c).$

$S_2 = 2a + 2(a \mod c).$

$S_3 = 2b + 2(b \mod c).$

Then

$S_2 - S_1 = (a - b) + [(a \mod c) - (b \mod c)].$

$S_3 - S_1 = (b - a) + [(b \mod c) - (a \mod c)] = - (S_2 - S_1).$

Clearly, you can't have $~(S_2 - S_1), ~(S_3 - S_1)$ both positive or both negative.